# Linking of template object files - different behavior with clang and gcc

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, linker, clang

There has been a lot questions about different behavior between gcc and clang. However i did not find the solution for my problem yet.

I use templates and i want to spread the definition and implementation of the class. I read about it (a lot) i am aware of the different possibilities. I choose the specific declaration, which templates i want to support. With:

```
   template class Temp<char>;
   template class Temp<double>;
```

I choose which templates i support, which actually works, if i put those lines at the end of the template.cc file. However with gcc i also can write it in the header file. Clang does not support it, i get linking errors.

But why? What is wrong with the declaration of used templates in the header file???

This is my toy example:

template.hh

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Temp
{
public:
    Temp(T data);
    virtual ~Temp (){};
    void print();

private:
    T data_;
};

//Only gcc can support this
//template class Temp<char>;
//template class Temp<double>
```

template.cc

```
#include "template.hh"                                                                                           

template<typename T>
Temp<T>::Temp(T data): data_(data)
{
}

template<typename T>
void Temp<T>::print()
{
    std::cout << data_ << " " << sizeof(data_) << std::endl;
}

//Delete those, if it is used in header
template class Temp<char>;
template class Temp<double>;
```

test.cc

```
#include "template.hh"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Temp<char> temp = Temp<char>('c');
    temp.print();

    Temp<double> temp2 = Temp<double>(1.0);
    temp2.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Desired output:

```
c  1
1  8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explicit instantiation of a function template is a definition. Explicit instantiation of a class template is a short-hand for instantiating all [non-template] member functions of the class template. Having multiple definitions of an entity in C++ results in a violation of the ODR-rule (One Definition Rules). Violations of the ODR-rule do not need to be diagnosed.

As a result, explicit instantiations of template belong into a ".cc" file. If you want to *declare* that a template will be explicitly instantiated in some translation unit, you can use `extern` template declarations, e.g.:

```
template <typename> void f();
template <typename> class F { /*...*/ };

extern template void f<int>();
extern template class F<int>();
```

`extern` template declarations allow templates to be defined in the header but inhibit implicit instantiation. Instead, the `extern` template declaration promises that there will be one translation unit providing an explicit instantiation.

Answer (score 3):

Explicit template instantiation belongs in the ".cc" implementation file, not the header.  If you want to declare it in the header, you can do so using `extern`:

```
extern template class Temp<char>;
extern template class Temp<double>;
```

This will avoid the multiply-defined symbols that you are probably experiencing with Clang otherwise.

It may be that GCC supports explicit instantiation in the header file, but this does not mean it is correct C++, only that GCC is being liberal in this case.  Don't rely on that.